# Pagination in OpenERP 7

Tags: python, xml, pagination, openerp-7

Where is Pagination python script is located in OpenERP-7. I want to give pagination for tabs as shown in figure.

We can give pagination for main menus. But how can I give pagination for tabs as shown below Image. Now I have written static code in XML I need to hard code dynamic pagination in python script.

```
<page string="History">
                        <div style="float:right">
                            <div class="oe_pager_value">
                                <span class="oe_list_pager_state">
                                    <span class="oe_form_pager_state">1 / 8</span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="oe_pager_group">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="oe_i" type="button" data-pager-action="previous">(</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="oe_i" type="button" data-pager-action="next">)</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                            <field name="history_line" readonly="context.get('ctx', False)">
                                <tree string="History Order Lines" create="false" delete="false">
                                    <field name = "s_no"/>
                                    <field name = "date_created"/>
                                    <field name = "created_by"/>
                                    <field name = "last_update"/>
                                    <field name = "last_update_by"/>
                                    <field name = "date_status_change"/>
                                    <field name = "status_change_by"/>
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                    </page>
```

So if I get pagination python script location in OpenERP 7 I will get some clues.

[image: Pagination]

Answer (score 0):

Refer this it will help all.

We can give pagination for two items/fields. One for menus and one for tabs.

For menus: just write one like code in `<field name="limit">15</field>` in **ir.actions.act_window** model. i.e.

```
<record id="action_program" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Program</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">lis.program</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="limit">15</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_program_filter"/>
    <field name="view_id" ref="program_tree"/>
</record>
```

For tab: go to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP
>   7.0-20140622-231040\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\static\src\js

File **view_list.js** Line num 117

```
limit: function () {
    if (this._limit === undefined) {
        this._limit = (this.options.limit
                    || this.defaults.limit
                    || (this.getParent().action || {}).limit
                    || 80);
    }
    return this._limit;
},
```

Change that default number 80 to your choice.